# Flex playing mp3 stream doesn't work

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, streaming

I've copied the sample code from Adobe for playing an mp3 stream in Flex mobile but it doesn't seem to work.

The stream i used as an example works perfectly fine in Winamp.

This is my code:

```
                import flash.net.*;
        import flash.media.*;
        private  var req:URLRequest;
        private  var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(8000, true);
        private   var s:Sound;
        private  var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

        private  function AudioOn():void
        {
            req = new URLRequest("http://stream2.srr.ro:8000");
            s = new Sound(req,context);
            channel=s.play();               
        }

                    private function onInit() : void { 
                         AudionOn();
                     }
```

Using the debbuger the s (sound) object has the following state:

```
           s.isBuffering is true; 
           s.isURLInaccesible is false; 
           s.bytesLoaded = 0 
           s.bytesTotal = 0;
```

This seems to be an easy task but why doensn't this example work ?

Thanks a lot!

Dan

Comment: Are you sure this question should be tagged with Flex?  You seem to be using ActionScript classes; but not Flex classes.

Comment: @Reboog711 I'm using Flex to build my mobile application. This is the sample from Adobe's site for audio streaming

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to modified your sound file by

1. Remove all metadata in the sound file.
2. Export it to a new MP3 file.
3. Is it too large to load? Try to add error event to listen.